Photon Unity Networking: Scene not being created
I'm trying to implement multiplayer in my Unity game. I'm using PUN2 as a multiplayer solution. I have encountered a problem where I can't join my room. I would get an error saying "Game doesn't exist." I have tried multiple times and have concluded that the problem is not with inputting the name of a room. Here is the code for joining a created room:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;

public class JoinPhotonRoom : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public TMP_InputField joinTo;
    public TMP_Text errorMessage;

    public string playerName;

    public bool usernameLoaded = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        GetPlayerDisplayName();
    }

    // Method to retrieve the player's display name from PlayFab
    void GetPlayerDisplayName()
    {
        // Call PlayFab to get player's account info
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfo(new GetAccountInfoRequest(), OnGetAccountInfoSuccess, OnGetAccountInfoFailure);
    }

    // Callback for successful retrieval of account info
    void OnGetAccountInfoSuccess(GetAccountInfoResult result)
    {
        // Set the playerName variable to the retrieved display name
        playerName = result.AccountInfo.TitleInfo.DisplayName;
        Debug.Log("Player Display Name: " + playerName);

        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName = playerName;
        usernameLoaded = true;
    }

    // Callback for failure to retrieve account info
    void OnGetAccountInfoFailure(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to get account info: " + error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }

    public void JoinRoom()
    {
        if (usernameLoaded)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(joinTo.text);
        }
    }

    public override void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);
        errorMessage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        errorMessage.text = message;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("MultiplayerScene");
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            print(roomList[i].Name);
        }
    }
}


I'm also using Playfab for managing player usernames and scores.
I tried debugging the issue. I think the problem is in my script for creating the room:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;

public class CreatePhotonRoom : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public TMP_Text username;

    public string playerName;

    void Awake()
    {
        GetPlayerDisplayName();
    }

    // Method to retrieve the player's display name from PlayFab
    void GetPlayerDisplayName()
    {
        // Call PlayFab to get player's account info
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfo(new GetAccountInfoRequest(), OnGetAccountInfoSuccess, OnGetAccountInfoFailure);
    }

    // Callback for successful retrieval of account info
    void OnGetAccountInfoSuccess(GetAccountInfoResult result)
    {
        // Set the playerName variable to the retrieved display name
        playerName = result.AccountInfo.TitleInfo.DisplayName;
        Debug.Log("Player Display Name: " + playerName);

        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName = playerName;
        CreateRoom();
    }

    // Callback for failure to retrieve account info
    void OnGetAccountInfoFailure(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to get account info: " + error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 2;
        roomOptions.IsVisible = true;
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(playerName, roomOptions, null);
    }

    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("RoomCreated");
        username.text = playerName;
    }

    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient && PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 2)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("MultiplayerScene");
        }
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        Debug.Log("Room list updated.");

        for (int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            print(roomList[i].Name);
        }
    }
}


OnCreatedRoom() is being called because I can see "RoomCreated" in the log. However, the function I added at the end for debugging does not appear to be called. Do you have any idea what the issue might be?
I can tell you this: The PlayFab username is being loaded correctly (the problem is not caused by wrongly entering room name) and the players have joined the lobby in a previous script.
I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions about this problem.

For the sake of testing, can you please try changing PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(joinTo.text); to PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(playerName);
just to make sure its getting the right value its expecting as you are using the playerName as room ID
